# token substitution using values from file and create multiple files , one for one substitution each

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have two files :

file1 :

```
key1
key2
key3
```

file2:

```
some useful or useless text
::tok::
some more useful or useless text
```

I want to create multiple files :

file_key1:

```
some useful or useless text
key1
some more useful or useless text
```

file_key2:

```
some useful or useless text
key2
some more useful or useless text
```

file_key3:

```
some useful or useless text
key3
some more useful or useless text
```

I am extreme noob when it comes to sed or awk. I can do the above using a perl script or bash script. Is there a way to do it using sed or awk?

Edit : as demanded the perl script i am using to do the above task

```
$newFileCount= 1;

open IFH,$filename || die "cannot open the file";

sub CreateNewFiles{

        my ($cid) = @_;
        open TIFH, $templateFile; # this is the template file file2 from the above problem description
        open OFH,">$templateFileTemp";
        while(<TIFH>) {
                s/::tok::/$cid/g;
                print OFH $_;
        }
        close TIFH;
        close OFH;
        move($templateFileTemp,$newFilePrefix.$newFileCount.".ext"); # using a library File::Copy for move operation

}
while(<IFH>) {
        chomp($_);
        $newFileCount= $newFileCount + 1;
        CreateNewFiles($_);

}
```

Comment: If you can do it in a perl or bash script, why do you want to do it in sed or awk? And if you did... it'd probably help elict good answers to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Sobrique I just wanted to learn sed/awk way of doing these things. and also i have been facing instances where i have to write perl scripts for smallest of tasks , I think there is definitely value in learning sed/awk which will save me a lot of time. anyway, please see the edit above , i have updated the question with the perl script

Comment: I just don't agree actually. `perl` is a programming language, and can do everything just fine.

Comment: Not saying perl is inadequate, It's my handicap to not be able to come up with scripts as quickly in perl. I might be completely wrong in assuming that sed/awk will speed things up for me but that is something i will have to   try and conclude. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

In awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                  # for the data file
    b=b (NR==1?"":ORS) $0  # buffer the records from the data file
    next                   # next record
}
{
    close(file)            # close previous file
    file="file_" $1        # name current file 
    t=b                    # t is for tmp, b for buffer, baby
    sub(/::tok::/,$1,t)    # replace token with the key
    print t > file         # dump the t to file
}' file2 file1             # mind the order
```

Comment: are NR FNR  ORS special keywords in awk?

Comment: @Ravi Yes. `NR` is the (global) number of records as opposed to `FNR`, current file's number of records and `ORS` is the output record separator; usually a record ends in a newline but necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$head f?
==> f1 <==
key1
key2
key3

==> f2 <==
some useful or useless text
::tok::
some more useful or useless text
```

---

```
$cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
file1=$1
file2=$2
while IFS= read line
do
awk -v line="$line"  '{gsub(/::tok::/,line); print > "fil_"line }'  $file2
done < $file1
```

---

```
$./script.sh f1 f2
$head fil_key?
==> fil_key1 <==
some useful or useless text
key1
some more useful or useless text

==> fil_key2 <==
some useful or useless text
key2
some more useful or useless text

==> fil_key3 <==
some useful or useless text
key3
some more useful or useless text
```